# sql server timeout when executed via web service trough stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

good afternoon.

i am testing my web application which utilizes ajax to communicate with the web service i noticed that when i am querying records from january to march 2014 it returns the expected result but beyond 3 months it returns this error

Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> The wait operation timed out -- executed trough the list of functions under my list of web services

now here is the view which the stored procedure uses to query

```
SELECT        ID, StationName, COUNT(pid) AS resultcount, MonthInt, YearDate, Month
FROM            dbo.displaystat
WHERE        (type = N'STN')
GROUP BY ID, StationName, MonthInt, YearDate, Month, type
ORDER BY resultcount, MonthInt
```

count (pid) -> PK is this a bad idea running a count on a primary key?

here is the stored procedure

```
USE [arrestedpersonsdb]
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[stnlevelrunningstat]
(
      @PageIndex INT = 1
      ,@PageSize INT = 10
      ,@RecordCount INT OUTPUT 
      ,@id int
      ,@year int
      ,@monthstart int
      ,@monthend int
    )
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here

      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
      (
            ORDER BY [MonthInt] ASC
      )AS RowNumber
      ,[ID]
      ,[StationName]
      ,[resultcount]
      ,[Month]
      ,[MonthInt]

      INTO #Results
      FROM [forstationstatistics]
      where (ID = @id) and (MonthInt between @monthstart and @monthend) and (YearDate = @year)
      SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*)
      FROM #Results

      SELECT * FROM #Results
      WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1

      DROP TABLE #Results
END
```

as you can see the count function is already done in the view my stored procedure simply pulls the record by month but as i said querying pass 3 months this error "The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding" is returned

Comment: I do not think that the problem is on sql. If your proc executes ok in tsql is ok. I believe the problem is in the amount of data than the service is called to give you in the webcall. So check your service web config for the amount of data.

Comment: hi i tried for 3 months and the size is 1.6 kb so i am guessing thst it will be at the range of 6kb when i query 12 months

Comment: Change readerQuota and generally check your binding in web config.

Comment: should i use datareader to load a dataset? i am using sqldataadapter

Comment: I do not think that will change the situation.

Comment: got a question is it ok that the sql server view above is obtaining its data trough another view?

Answer (score 0):

this answer may not work with the same problem but on my part the culprit was the nested views when i changed it to non nested views the performance and the speed was noticeably a far cry from the nested views